# Get Identifier field from Firebase Auth Console

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I'm trying to get the email from the user that's currently authenticated using the Facebook Firebase provider. The email is listed under the **Identifier** field inside the Project's Firebase Authentication Console:
[image]

However when I invoke `firebase.auth().currentUser` the user information loads, however the email field is `null`. Any ideas on how to get the Identifier (which is where I see the email address) from Firebase? Is this even possible?

Below is the code I'm using:

```
    componentDidMount() {

      let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      let name, email, photoUrl, uid, emailVerified;

      if (user !== null) {
       name = user.displayName;
       email = user.email;
       photoUrl = user.photoURL;
       emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
       uid = user.uid;

       console.log(name, email, photoUrl, emailVerified, uid);
      }

    }
```

**Note**: Prevent creation of multiple accounts with the same email address is enabled in Firebase. Also, Facebook API permissions are set to `['public_profile', 'email']`

Comment: why not use console.log directly with "user" instead of listing those fields separately?

Comment: So when you call `console.log`, everything else is logged, just not the email?

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I inspected `user` and found a `providerData` property that contained the info I was looking for (including the email). See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some testing and debugging I found that the `email` field will be populated if you're using a regular Firebase Email/Password Sign In method. However, if you're using another Sign In provider method such as Facebook, the email field will appear `null` (not sure why).

Further inspection of the `user` object revealed a `providerData` property.
It's an array that contains all the provider information (including the email address):

[image]

So, I updated my code to accommodate this:

```
    componentDidMount() {

      let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

      let name, email, photoUrl, uid, emailVerified;

      if (user) {
        name = user.displayName; 
        email = user.email;
        photoUrl = user.photoURL; 
        emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
        uid = user.uid;

        if (!email) {
          email = user.providerData[0].email;
        }

        console.log(name, email, photoUrl, emailVerified, uid);
      }

    }
```

Comment: I had a similar problem when using Firebase Auth with Facebook. I think it's time we [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the getEmail() method always returns data for three sign-in possibilities (if user gave authorization to my app to show/use email): Sign in with Email, Sign in with Google, Sign in with Facebook.

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
Log.v(TAG,"user.getEmail():"+user.getEmail());

if (user.getEmail() == null){
    // User did not authorize the app to show/user email
}
else {
   Log.v(TAG,"user.getEmail():"+user.getEmail());   
}
```